# How do you convert an instance of generic T into a concrete instance in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement this pattern:

```
use std::any::Any;
use std::fmt::Debug;

trait CommandHandler<TCommand> {
    fn execute(&self, data: TCommand);
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct FooCommand {}

struct FooCommandHandler {}

impl CommandHandler<FooCommand> for FooCommandHandler {
    fn execute(&self, data: FooCommand) {
        println!("Foo");
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct BarCommand {}

struct BarCommandHandler {}

impl CommandHandler<BarCommand> for BarCommandHandler {
    fn execute(&self, data: BarCommand) {
        println!("Bar");
    }
}

fn execute<T>(command: T)
where
    T: Any + Debug,
{
    println!("Command: {:?}", command);
    match (&command as &Any).downcast_ref::<FooCommand>() {
        Some(c) => (FooCommandHandler {}).execute(c),
        None => {}
    };
    match (&command as &Any).downcast_ref::<BarCommand>() {
        Some(c) => (BarCommandHandler {}).execute(c),
        None => {}
    };
}

fn main() {
    (FooCommandHandler {}).execute(FooCommand {});
    (BarCommandHandler {}).execute(BarCommand {});
    execute(FooCommand {});
    execute(BarCommand {});
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:37:51
   |
37 |         Some(c) => (FooCommandHandler {}).execute(c),
   |                                                   ^ expected struct `FooCommand`, found &FooCommand
   |
   = note: expected type `FooCommand`
              found type `&FooCommand`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:41:51
   |
41 |         Some(c) => (BarCommandHandler {}).execute(c),
   |                                                   ^ expected struct `BarCommand`, found &BarCommand
   |
   = note: expected type `BarCommand`
              found type `&BarCommand`
```

How can I implement the `execute()` method in a way that preserves the following requirements:

- The type `XCommand` should be totally naive of the `XCommandHandler`'s that execute it.
- Multiple implementations of `CommandHandler<X>` may exist.
- The command handler receives (and consumes) the concrete command instance, not a reference to it (making duplicate dispatch of commands impossible).

In essence, I have a generic function `fn foo<T>(v: T)` and a I wish to dispatch to a number of concrete functions `fn foo1(v: Foo)`, `fn foo2(v: Bar)`; how do I do that?

Is `transmute` the only option?

Note that this is distinct from what `Any::downcast_ref` does, which is return an `&Foo`, not `Foo` from the generic value v.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go via `Box`, like so:

```
fn execute<T>(command: T)
where
    T: Any + Debug,
{
    println!("Command: {:?}", command);
    let any: Box<Any> = Box::new(command);

    let any = match any.downcast() {
        Ok(c) => return (FooCommandHandler {}).execute(*c),
        Err(any) => any,
    };

    let any = match any.downcast() {
        Ok(c) => return (BarCommandHandler {}).execute(*c),
        Err(any) => any,
    };

    let _ = any; // avoid unused variable error
    panic!("could not downcast command");
}
```

---

"But I don't *wanna* use a `Box`!"

Just use `Box`.

"But it's an allocation!  I've measured the above code and proven beyond a shadow of a doubt that it's a bottleneck!"

What?  *Really?*

"You can't prove otherwise."

*Oh fine*.  But I *do not* guarantee that this will work in all cases.  This is treading into "blow yourself up" territory.  Do not do this unless you *know* you need to:

```
fn execute<T>(command: T)
where
    T: Any + Debug,
{
    use std::any::TypeId;
    use std::mem;

    println!("Command: {:?}", command);

    macro_rules! do_cast {
            ($t:ty, $h:expr) => {
                if TypeId::of::<T>() == TypeId::of::<$t>() {
                    let casted: $t = mem::transmute_copy(&command);
                    mem::forget(command); // we CANNOT let command drop.
                    $h.execute(casted);
                    return;
                }
            };
        }

    unsafe {
        do_cast!(FooCommand, FooCommandHandler {});
        do_cast!(BarCommand, BarCommandHandler {});
    }

    panic!("could not downcast command");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a quick summary of the accepted answer:

Where `&Any` only has:

```
pub fn downcast_ref<T>(&self) -> Option<&T> where T: Any
```

`Box<Any>` implements:

```
pub fn downcast<T>(self) -> Result<Box<T>, Box<Any + 'static>> where T: Any
```

However, for complicated reasons, the documentation is on [`Box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.downcast) not on [`Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/any/trait.Any.html#method.downcast_mut).